# ¿Cómo acceder a una sola fila en una table pivot en Laravel cuando se repite el foreign key en cuestión?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, pivot, querybuilder

Resulta, señores, que tengo una tabla pivote donde hay tres claves, la autonumérica de la tabla, la de la película en cuestión, y la del usuario. Es una tabla de alquileres.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un usuario puede alquilar muchas películas (más de una vez) y una película por muchos usuarios. Supongamos que nos vamos al panel del usuario en concreto, vemos el siguiente fallo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y es que, como vemos que la clave que se repite, al acceder a una película, me asigna el mismo valor siempre y cuando lo recorro con el foreach, pues la consulta es esta y creo que ahí está el fallo, pero no encuentro la manera:

```
return DB::table('movie_user')->join('movies', 'movie_user.movie_id', '=', 'movies.id')
            ->where('movies.id', $id)->whereNotNull('fecha_alquiler')->whereNull('devolucion')->get();
```

He probado con last, con orderby desc, etc y después con un limit de 1, pero qué va, siempre me entra en la primera fila y se multiplica los valores en la vista, a la que tengo puesto un if que si cumple que el valor de devolución sea NULL me aparezca el botón de devolver.

Mi idea era hacerle un pluck de devolución y que si estaba null mostrara el botón devolver, pero resulta que claro, si siempre entra en el mismo registro, o me lo muestra en todos, o en ninguno.

Comment: De tu imagen de tu tabla solo deseas acceder a los renglones donde devolución no sea NULL? No termino de entender la duda

Comment: Podrías acceder a la película (que tenga el mismo id) buscando la fecha más tarde en la cual esta fue alquilada, o haciendo un group by por id tambien

Comment: Voy a probar eso desde luego. Un saludo y gracias.